# How i can Insert filename inside it in batch

Tags: python, bash, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a few thousand txt files and I need to insert the filename inside each one between <> on the second line.
For example:
I have lot of files like this

```
    225248F040.txt
    225248F060.txt
    225248F070.txt
    225446F020.txt...
```

Their content header:

```
    %
    (PROGRAM.....225248F040)
    (PROGRAMMER.....NAME)
    (DATE....... 28.APR.2022)
    (TIME............. 10.26)
    (MACHINE........DX250)
    (================================)
```

I need to add the name between <> on the second line of each one, looking like this:

```
    %
    <225248F040.txt>
    (PROGRAM.....225248F040)
    (PROGRAMMER.....NAME)
    (DATE....... 28.APR.2022)
    (TIME............. 10.26)
    (MACHINE........DX250)
    (================================)
```

I can use CMD, Bash linux, Powershell or Python.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was able to add the filename in the first line and without <> with CMD:

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%g in ('dir *.txt /A-D /B 2^>nul') do ( 
>tmp.tmp echo %%g
echo/>>tmp.tmp  
copy /Y tmp.tmp + "%%g" tmp2.tmp 
echo move /Y tmp2.tmp "%%g"
) 
exit /b

Comment: That appears to be [[tag:batch-file]] code. If you want help with batch file code, then submit it as an [edit] to your question, and remove all references to [[tag:python]], [[tag:powershell]], [[tag:linux]] and [[tag:bash]]. Spamming those tags, simply tells us you want anyone to perform a free code writing service for you, and that is not the purpose of this site. Limit your question to one specific code issue, and one specific language. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directories are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 set "inserted="
 for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e in ("%sourcedir%\%%b") do (
 echo %%e
 if not defined inserted echo ^<%%b^>
 set "inserted=y"
 )
)>"%destdir%\%%b"


GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Simply read each line from each file, and insert the required data (filename in `%%b`) after the first line, using `inserted` as a switch to determine whether the extra data has already been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

```
path_to_file = '/home/user/Documents/path_to_file.txt'

with open(path_to_file) as f:
    source_contents = f.read()
    source_splitlist = source_contents.split('\n')

if len(source_splitlist) > 0:
    source_splitlist.insert(1, f'<{path_to_file}>')
    destination_altered = '\n'.join(source_splitlist)

    with open(path_to_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(destination_altered)

else:
    print('Not happy, file to short')
```

Comment: i'll try and update you

Comment: what code is this ? bash ?

Comment: Its Python, not sure why it didnt get all the fancy colors when i pushed it